# SplFileObject + LimitIterator + offset

Tags: php, offset, splfileobject

I have data file with two lines (two lines just for my example, in real, that file can contain millions of lines) and I use SplFileObject and LimitIterator with offseting. But this combination have strange behaviour in some cases:

```
$offset = 0;
$file = new \SplFileObject($filePath);
$fileIterator = new \LimitIterator($file, $offset, 100);
foreach ($fileIterator as $key => $line) {
  echo $key;
}
```

Output is: **01**

But with **$offset** set to **1**, output is blank (foreach doesn't iterate any line).

My data file contain this:

```
{"generatedAt":1434665322,"numRecords":"1}
{"id":"215255","code":"NB000110"}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's important or not, but there is a missing `"` at the end of the first ligne of your data file.

Comment: It's just a typo when I formated it as code.

Comment: So, this can be marked as PHP bug? Or confusing behaviour at least? I understand that correctly?

Comment: I certainly think it is 'confusing'. I didn't expect that behaviour.  I also think it messes up the `foreach` loop processing. I think it is an 'edge' case of 'end of file' processing that is not handled correctly. The fault is with `SplFileObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required:

Use `SplFileObject` to process a number of records from:

- a given start record number
- for a given number of records or until `EOF`.

The issue is that `SplFileObject` gets confused as regards the `last record` in the file. This prevents it working correctly in `foreach` loops.

This code uses the `SplFileObject` and 'skip records' and 'processes records'. Alas, It cannot use `foreach` loops.

- Skip a number of records from the start of the file (`$offset`).
- Process a given number of records or unit the end of file (`$recordsToProccess`)

The code:

```
<?php

$filePath = __DIR__ . '/Q30932555.txt';
// $filePath = __DIR__ . '/Q30932555_1.txt';

$offset = 1;
$recordsToProcess = 100;

$file = new \SplFileObject($filePath);

// skip the records
$file->seek($offset);

$recordsProcessed = 0;
while (     ($file->valid() || strlen($file->current()) > 0)
         &&  $recordsProcessed < $recordsToProcess
       ) {
    $recordsProcessed++;
    echo '<br />', 'current: ', $file->key(), ' ', $file->current();
    $file->next();
}
```

Comment: It is a little 'clumsy' but it seems to do to do the job.

Comment: Of course, this solved my problem. But I really want to use LimitIterator because it has much more readable code :(

Comment: @MiroslavHruška, i did try! Alas, i couldn't get anything sensible when using the 'LimitIterator'.

Comment: I know, thanks Ryan. I will report this as PHP bug and we will see.

Comment: @MiroslavHruška,  I tried to do a 'decorator' to fix the issues - It is a 'hard' problem to solve. The code i have provided works. It is 'clumsy'.  I cannot work out how to use a `foreach` loop given what happens. I don't like the code I produced. :-/ It works but is 'fudging things' ;-/

Comment: The issue is that `SplFileObject->valid()` returns `false` when it reaches the last record in the list. It should return `false` after advancing to the next record after the last one. Hence the test for the `current` record having a length even though 'valid' is reporting false. ;-/

Answer (score 0):

Reading the related PHP bug [65601](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65601) suggests adding the `READ_AHEAD` flag will fix this. Tested and works as you expected it to.

```php
$offset = 0;
$file = new \SplFileObject($filePath);
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
$fileIterator = new \LimitIterator($file, $offset, 100);
foreach ($fileIterator as $key => $line) {
  echo $key;
}
```