# LimitIterator offset 1 with 2 elements

Tags: php, csv

The problem I'm facing is that I have a SplFileObject that reads a CSV file, then I wrap it into a LimitIterator.

The CSV file has 2 rows, header, and 1 row, I set the LimitIterator offset to 1 and I can't reach over it, seems some internal problems with the indexing.

here is the code:

```
    $csvFile = new \SplFileObject($fileName);
    $csvFile->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    $iterator = new \LimitIterator($csvFile, 1);

    /** @var \LimitIterator $it */
    foreach ($iterator as $it) {

        list($.., $.., $..) = $it;
        $result[] = [
            ...
        ];
    }


    return $result;
```

The code works well if the CSV has 3 lines (header and 2 rows), but only with header and 1 row, it doesn't work.

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code with simple csv - it works. Check your data, maybe it is corrupted?

Comment: Could I see your simple CSV ? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is related to PHP bug [65601](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65601), which suggests adding the `READ_AHEAD` flag will fix this. Tested and works as you expected it to.

```php
    $csvFile->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV | \SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
```

See also [SplFileObject + LimitIterator + offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932555/splfileobject-limititerator-offset)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use the fopen and fgetcsv functions for this as below;

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("myFile.csv", "r");

if ($handle != false)
{
    $header_row_handled = false;
    while ($datarow = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")
    {
        if (!$header_row_handled)
        {
            $header_row_handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Whatever you need */
            $dataparta = $datarow[0];
            $datapartb = $datarow[1];
            $datapartc = $datarow[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Looping means you can just skip the first row each time and perhaps use less resource for this as you don't have as many objects floating around

The [php.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) should help you out too

Comment: I suppose question is not how to loop over dataset. But why certain selected approach does not work.

Comment: @u_mulder - well, yes, this is purely an alternative method to achieve the same result

Comment: That was the approach we were using before, but I was refactoring this to some more modern approach, so I could have something really easy, readable and removing the conditional inside the loop.

Comment: @redigaffi - sometimes, reinventing the wheel isn't the best thing to do, simplicity is great at times, IMO it boils sown to "why fix what isn't broken" :)

Comment: Yes I know that, but I always try to improve all. And removing these conditionals means simpler and easier code. (And less cyclomatic complexity too). But thanks for the help.